# How can I get a proper URI in Java, Windows

Tags: java, windows, url, webview, uri

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), it says:

## Windows

> Here are some examples which may be accepted by some applications on Windows systems, referring to the same, local file c:\WINDOWS\clock.avi
>
> ```
> file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> ```
>
> Here is the URI as understood by the Windows Shell API:[2]
>
> ```
> file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> ```

---

Suppose, I need conversion of filenames type: `C:\WINDOWS\clock.avi` to URIs for use in a JavaFX WebView as href for tags, css, links etc. etc.

The app intercepts clicks on the links, analyzes and performs actions, depending on the link  (runs pdf, internet, music etc.)

But, I don't manage to generate the proper URI from filenames to be used in those webview pages.

These are the results that Java provides:

### Code

```
private static void print(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName = "c:\\WINDOWS\\clock.avi";
    print("0 - " + new File(fileName).toString());
    print("1 - " + new File(fileName).toURI().toString());
    print("2 - " + new File(fileName).toURI().toURL().toString());
    print("3 - " + new URL(new File(fileName).toURI().toString()).toString());
}
```

### Results:

```
 0 - c:\WINDOWS\clock.avi
 1 - file:/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
 2 - file:/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
 3 - file:/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
```

So, No 1, 2 and 3 are all same, and none of them are correct - as I infer from URI rules. Is it a Java bug?

Is there a proper way to get exactly the `file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi` uri from a file path `c:\WINDOWS\clock.avi` instead of the resulting `file:/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi`, which is reported as wrong in various places?

The StackOverflow most popular answers is use No. 1 or No. 2, but the above shows that the results are not correct URIs.

Comment: Using `java.nio.file.Path.toUri()` rather than `File.toURI()` gives me `file:///`. If you're already using `File` extensively you can simply call `File.toPath()` to convert it to a `Path`. As to why there's a difference in behavior, I don't know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [`toUri()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toUri()) on a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) yields the URI you want. I don't see anything in the documentation that states this is guaranteed behavior, however; or if it is in the documentation, I'm just not recognizing it. So, in case this behavior is subject to change, note that I only tried this using *JDK 10.0.1*.

In my opinion, if you can switch your code to use the file API introduced with NIO2 (Java 7), rather than `java.io` that would be ideal. If you can't or don't want to for whatever reason, then you can convert a `File` into a `Path` using [`File.toPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath()) (and vice versa using [`Path.toFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile())).

Using this code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop");
System.out.printf("File.toURI() = %s%nFile.toPath().toUri() = %s%n", 
        file.toURI(), file.toPath().toUri());
```

Gave me this output:

```
File.toURI() = file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/
File.toPath().toUri() = file:///C:/Users/Username/Desktop/
```